# How to get output of exec()?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, exec

How do I get the output of a program ran by exec(). Let's say I have this code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int fid = fork();
    if(fid == 0) {
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
    wait();
    return 0;
}
```

How can the parent process get the output of the ls command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` family of functions completely replaces the current process.  However, they do not close file descriptors unless they marked close-on-exec.  Thus, the typical way to do this is to create a pipe where the read side belongs to the parent and the write side belongs to the child.

This would look something like this (error checking omitted and obviously inefficient):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int pipefd[2];
    int status;
    uint8_t buf[256];

    pipe(pipefd);

    int fid = fork();
    if(fid == 0) {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
    close(pipefd[1]);

    while (read(pipefd[0], buf, 1) > 0)
        write(1, buf, 1);
    wait(&status);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that to attach the pipe file descriptor to standard output (FD 1), you need to use `dup2`.  You also need to close the ends of the pipe you're not using, or you may never end up reaching end of file.

If you're interested in the exit status, `wait` (or `waitpid`) will provide that for you; see the manual page for how to determine if it exited normally and if so, what that status was.